# Jquery method selection for moving to next parents child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having difficultly getting the right Method to target the right element.

HTML

```
 <div class="side-blog">
   <div class="side-nav-block-item">
      <h4>Click me</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="side-nav-block-item">
     Stuff I want to Slide up
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery is what I'm working with. I know I need to replace the parent or add to it to move back down the tree, I've tried closest() & next() but couldn't get it to work.

```
$('.side-blog h4').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $(this).parent('.side-nav-block-item').slideUp('normal');
  } else {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $(this).parent('.side-nav-block-item').slideDown('normal');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.parent('.side-nav-block-item').next()[$(this).hasClass('on') ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']('normal');
$this.toggleClass('on');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uzp2J/)

Answer (score 1):

**[this](http://jsfiddle.net/QCdvk/)** will work for you

using next() will get the result.

```
$('.side-blog h4').click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {

    $(this).toggleClass('on');
        $(this).parent('.side-nav-block-item').next().slideDown('normal');
} else {

    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $(this).parent('.side-nav-block-item').next().slideUp('normal');

    }
});
```